# How do I get the list of dates in a quarter from a specific date in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to find out all the dates from the supplied date's quarter (In this particular case, I'm trying to search all sales made from the quarter of the first sale).

My initial attempt below was to extract the month and year from the supplied date and use it as a condition when looking for the records, unfortunately I don't know how to supply the where clause with multiple conditions.

```
DECLARE @FirstSale DateTime = (SELECT TOP 1 [Sale].[DateCreated] FROM [Sale] ORDER BY [Sale].[DateCreated] ASC)
DECLARE @FirstSaleMonth int = Month(@FirstSale)
DECLARE @FirstSaleYear int = Year(@FirstSale)

SELECT [Sale].[DateCreated] FROM [Sale]
WHERE Month([Sale].[DateCreated]) =  
CASE 
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 1 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 2 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 3
        THEN 1 OR 2 OR 3    
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 4 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 5 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 6
        Then 4 OR 5 OR 6
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 7 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 8 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 9
        Then 7 OR 8 OR 9
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 10 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 11 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 12
        Then 10 OR 11 OR 12
END
AND Year([Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleYear
```

So what I ended up doing was just repeating the condition with varying results that would eventually hit the expected conditions

```
WHERE Month([Sale].[DateCreated]) =  
CASE 
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 1 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 2 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 3
        THEN 1
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 4 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 5 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 6
        Then 4
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 7 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 8 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 9
        Then 7
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 10 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 11 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 12
        Then 10
END
AND Year([Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleYear

OR

Month([Sale].[DateCreated]) = 
CASE 
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 1 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 2 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 3
        THEN 2
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 4 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 5 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 6
        Then 5
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 7 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 8 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 9
        Then 8
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 10 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 11 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 12
        Then 11
END
AND Year([Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleYear

OR

Month([Sale].[DateCreated]) = 
CASE 
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 1 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 2 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 3
        THEN 3
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 4 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 5 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 6
        Then 6
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 7 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 8 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 9
        Then 9
    WHEN @FirstSaleMonth = 10 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 11 OR @FirstSaleMonth = 12
        Then 12
END
AND Year([Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleYear
```

But I feel like it's unnecessarily long and I've used the same conditions multiple times. I'm still learning and I wanted to know if there's a more efficient way of doing it so that I could possibly apply it in the future?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Oh I apologize, it's SQL Server, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with quarters then.

```
DECLARE @FirstSale DateTime = (SELECT TOP 1 [Sale].[DateCreated] FROM [Sale] ORDER BY [Sale].[DateCreated] ASC)
DECLARE @FirstSaleQuarter int = DATEPART(QUARTER, @FirstSale)
DECLARE @FirstSaleYear int = Year(@FirstSale)

SELECT 
    [Sale].[DateCreated] 
FROM 
    [Sale]
WHERE 
    DATEPART(QUARTER, [Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleQuarter AND 
    Year([Sale].[DateCreated]) = @FirstSaleYear
```

But the best option that is SARGable (can use indexes properly) would be using ranges (avoid applying functions to the table's columns in the `WHERE`):

```
DECLARE @FirstSale DateTime = (SELECT TOP 1 [Sale].[DateCreated] FROM [Sale] ORDER BY [Sale].[DateCreated] ASC)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(
    Year(@FirstSale),
    (3 * (DATEPART(QUARTER, @FirstSale) - 1) + 1,
    1)

DECLARE @EndDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @StartDate)

SELECT 
    [Sale].[DateCreated] 
FROM 
    [Sale]
WHERE 
    [Sale].[DateCreated] >= @StartDate AND
    [Sale].[DateCreated] < @EndDate
```

Comment: Amazing work! This is why I love SO, I don't only learn from answers strictly related to my question, I also get to learn different and much more efficient techniques/methods that I could apply in the future.